# Como faço para trabalhar com uma String com parametros?

Tags: java

A pergunta parece ser simples e ingênua, mas nunca precisei usar isso, eu possuo uma String e dentro dela quero colocar parametros para que sejam preenchidos posteriormente, como em php

`$string = "o meu nome é $nome";`

ou como em c, mas em c é para mostrar na tela, no caso eu quero trabalhar com a String.
`printf("meu nome é %s", nome);`

Em java ja trabalhei com algo parecido mas quando se trabalha com conexão com o banco de dados usando `PreparedStatement`.

O meu problema real é:
eu possuo uma String nesse formato

`https://{paíz}.dominio.com.{paíz}/api/page`
A primeiro momento o mais óbvio é fazer concatenações, mas como existem várias strings nesse formato, quando ouver futuras manutenções acredito que ficara um tanto mais trabalhoso.

Comment: Eu sei, mas alguma função deve retornar uma nova string. Preciso de algo parecido com os PreparedStatement que parametriza a String SQL

Comment: Eu estou ciente que String são imutáveis. Eu quero parametrizar uma String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As únicas soluções que vejo é usar uma class externa como [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) ou simplesmente usar a função static `format` da class `String`. Aqui fica um simples exemplo:

```
import java.util.Formatter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Formatter f = new Formatter();
        f.format("My name is %s%n", "James");

        String firstName = f.toString();
        String lastName = String.format("My last name is %s%n", "Bond");

        System.out.println(firstName);
        System.out.println(lastName);

        f.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, apenas o String.format resolve, eu vi aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643610/java-including-variables-within-strings, Não precisei usar esse Formatter

Answer (score 5):

## StrSubstitutor

Outra opção adequada para substituições simples de variáveis é o [`StrSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) do Apache Commons.

Exemplo:

```
Map valuesMap = HashMap();
valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog"); 
String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}."; 
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap); 
String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

A desvantagem dessa  classe é ter que usar uma biblioteca à parte.

Porém ela é muito útil, por exemplo, se você quer deixar o usuário digitar um template parametrizado onde você vai fornecer o valor das variáveis e **não quer opções avançadas de formatação**.

Um exemplo é se você quer deixar o usuário entrar um padrão de caminho para um arquivo de log rotativo. Poderia ser assim:

```
/temp/logs/acessos-${data}.log.${numeroArquivo}
```

E aí o sistema aplica as variáveis `data` e `numeroArquivo` ao gravar o log.

É possível modificar o prefixo e o sufixo das variáveis usando outro construtor da classe `StrSubstitutor`, então não é preciso ficar preso ao padrão `${` e `}`.

**Esse seria um caso mais aproximado ao que se pretende na pergunta.**

## MessageFormat

Além do padrão do `Formatter` ou `String.format()`, existe uma opção um pouco mais avançada que tem suporte inclusive para pluralizar textos, o que é mais adequado se a intenção é parametrizar os textos da aplicação e fazer Internacionalização e Localização.

Trata-se do [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

Exemplo:

```
int planet = 7; 
String event = "a disturbance in the Force"; 
String result = MessageFormat.format( "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.", 
    planet, new Date(), event);
```

## Considerações

Note que essas classes tem aplicações específicas e seu uso é desnecessário nos casos de uso mais simples e comuns.

Comment: Cara StrSubstitutor é muito legal. Nunca imaginei algo do tipo. Muito bom saber obrigado.

Comment: @nbro Eu diria que realmente são desnecessárias para a maioria dos casos, somente tendo aplicações mais específicas. É preciso compreender o propósito delas. Com o `format` você tem apenas acesso posicional aos parâmetros enquanto o `StrSubstitutor` permite criar templates com variáveis nomeadas baseadas em qualquer mapa, inclusive variáveis de ambiente. Por exemplo, é útil para permitir ao usuário entrar templates de caminhos de diretório. Já `MessageFormat` é bom para L10n e I18n, então é o caminho para manter mensagens coerentes com os valores numéricos sem encher o código de IFs/ternários

Comment: @nbro Eu li o que escreveste, mas neste caso minha compreensão do trecho *inúteis a maior parte do tempo* foi diferente do que explicaste agora.

Comment: @nbro Obrigado pelo feedback, foi bastante útil.